# getting null in InAppPurchase product name and description

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase

My app was okay a few days ago. But from past 4-5 days when I retrieve product list from app store the product name and description is null but its identifier and price is okay.

I didn't changed anything after last working code. What might be the reason, any hints?

Comment: Whoever down voted can you explain the reason?

Comment: Make a fresh provisioning profile

Comment: @Jef > Tried but no luck with that.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. The reason was my InApp Purchase product description was more than 255 characters. But when I first create the products it accepted the description. After a few month it was returning null. Hope this helps someone.